# Calling an API returns expected JSONArray, found JSONObject

Tags: json, api, go

I'm calling an API from Go and trying to push json string data from another api call into it.

I can hand craft the calls using a payload like

payload := strings.NewReader('[{"value1":333, "value2":444}]'

and everything is happy.

I'm now trying to covert this to take the json string {"value1":333, "value2":444} as an input parameter of type string to a function, but when I try and use that as the payload, the api is responding with

expected type: JSONArray, found: JSONObject

I naively tried setting the input to the function as []string and appending the data to an array as the input, but then strings.NewReader complained that it was being fed an array.. which is was.

I'm at a loss to work out how to convert a string of json into a json array that the api will be happy with.

I tried just surrounding the string with [] but the compiler threw a fit about incorrect line termination.

Must have been doing something wrong with the string, surrounding the {} with [] let the function pass the data, but there must be a better way than this.

Any ideas, or am I making this harder than it should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track with the brackets, but you actually need to append the characters to the string. For example:

```golang
str := `{"value1":333, "value2":444}`
str = "[" + str + "]"
// [{"value1":333, "value2":444}]
```

https://play.golang.org/p/rWHCLDCAngd

If you use brackets outside a string or rune literal, then it is parsed as Go language syntax.